# Extracting single value from column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple pandas question regarding extracting a single column value

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [15,56,23,84], 'B' : [10,20,33,25]})
df

     A    B
0    15   10
1    56   20
2    23   33
3    84   55

x = df[df['A'] == 23]
x
```

outputs

```
    A    B
2  23    33
```

However, I only want to get the value in column B i.e. 33. How do I get that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My preferred way is Jeff's using loc  (it's generally good practice to avoid working on copies, especially if you might later do assignment).

You can eek some more performance by not creating a Series for the boolean mask, just a numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, 2000).reshape(-1, 2),
                  columns=list('AB'))

In [21]: %timeit df.loc[df.A == 23, 'B']
1000 loops, best of 3: 532 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit df['B'][df.A == 23]
1000 loops, best of 3: 432 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit df.loc[df.A.values == 23, 'B']  # preferred
1000 loops, best of 3: 294 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit df['B'].loc[df.A.values == 23]
1000 loops, best of 3: 197 µs per loop
```

*I'm not sure why this is so slow tbh, maybe this usecase could be improved...? (I'm not sure where the the extra 100us is spent)...*

However, if you are just interested in the *values* of B and not their corresponding index (and the subframe) it's much faster just to use the numpy arrays directly:

```
In [25]: %timeit df.B.values[df.A.values == 23]
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: With larger DataFrames the difference is much less significant... 100us seems to be pretty constant.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed analysis, In your last example, df.B.values[df.A.values == 23], is there any way I can replace 'B' by a variable instead?

Comment: My column name is computed at run time. In the other approaches I can use the variable name, but not in your last example (which I would like to use because of its speed).

Comment: @user308827 yes definitely, you can use df['B'] notation, so if `A='A'` and `B='B'` you can do: `df[B].values[df[A].values == 23]`.

Answer (score 5):

Simply: `df['B'][df['A'] == 23]`

Thanks @Jeff.

And the speed comparisons:

```
In [30]:

%timeit df['B'][df['A'] == 23].values
1000 loops, best of 3: 813 µs per loop
In [31]:

%timeit df.loc[df['A'] == 23, 'B']
1000 loops, best of 3: 976 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get: 2     33. Is there a way to just get the value I need, i.e. 33?

Comment: `df['B'][df['A'] == 23].values` if you don't mind a `numpy` `scalar`, does it has to be a plain `float`? I think is better this way, if you have multiple values, the return will be a `numpy` `array`.

Comment: don't use chained indexing, instead do: ``df.loc[df['A'] == 23, 'B']``; that was you can set as well (the above will show a warning if you try to see)

Comment: A simple float would have been nice, but this seems to work too. I just do df['B'][df['A'] == 23].values[0] or for Jeff's approach: df.loc[df['A'] == 23, 'B'].values[0]

Comment: @Jeff, is your way faster?

Comment: safer, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy. You should ALWAYS multi-axis index this way.